# Pass custom field value from related List Button (URL)

Tags: apex

This is my first post here. I need to create a custom button that would go to a specific Account record type to create a new Account. In my requirements, I need to pass a custom field `ci_Household` to New Account form. I am able to get to form using URL for my button but my field is not populating.

I have created a custom button on account object and point the URL to following URL.

Added new button to Related List

[https://ci--dm.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Account/new?&recordTypeId=012230000004TVPCC2&defaultFieldValues=NumberOfEmployees=35000&ci_Household={!Account.Id](https://ci--dm.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Account/new?&recordTypeId=012230000004TVPCC2&defaultFieldValues=NumberOfEmployees=35000&ci_Household=%7B!Account.Id))}

`ci_Household` field is a lookup field to account object. Field is not getting populated with Account that the user is on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm)?  It looks like you are missing the  `__c` portion of your custom field name.

Comment: Thanks David. I tried with API name and it doesn't work as well. Another challemge is that even if I can op new Account screen, how are we supposed to pass record type section. If I hard code RecordTypeId, it would be different in production org. Here is my URL: https://ci--dm.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Account/new?defaultFieldValues=
    Name={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)},
    OwnerId={!Account.OwnerId},
    AccountNumber={!Account.AccountNumber},
    NumberOfEmployees=35000,
    ci_Household__c={!Account.Id}